# Circular row switch in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose there is 5X6 table -

```
<script>
    // appending the table with the fields . 
    $("body").append("<table><tbody></tbody></table>");
    (function () {
        for (var row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
            $("tbody").append("<tr></tr>")
            for (var col = 1; col <= 6; col++) {
                $("tr:last").append("<td></td>");
                $("td:last").append(row + '-' + col);
            }
        }
    })()
</script>
```

and I want to do a ***circular switch** on it row  -

```
<script>
    function switchDown() {
        for (var row = 0; row <= 4; row++) {
            var temp = $("tr:eq( (row+1)%4 )");
            $("tr:eq(row)").insertAfter(temp);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above function doesn't apply any change on the table .

**Edit:**

- **circular switch** - means each index go to (index+1)'nd index , i.e -

the table before switch -

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
```

after switch it would be -

```
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
```

and after one more switch it would be  -

```
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
```

and after one more switch it would be as it was in the beginning .

and so on...

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to do a circular switch on it row`?

Comment: Are you actually calling `switchDown` function somewhere ? Are you including jQuery ? Please help us to help you by creating a fiddle out of this.

Comment: 1st would be 2nd ... 2nd would be 3nd ... 5nd would be 1st  .

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, but it seems the expression `"tr:eq( (row+1)%4 )"` is validated as a String. Try `"tr:eq(" + (row+1)%4 + ")"`.

Comment: @Bartdude : I described some more in the edit .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calculating expressions with the `row` variable in JavaScript, jQuery cannot evaluate it ;)

```
for (var row = 0  ; row <= 4 ; row++) {
    var index = (row + 1) % 4;
    var temp = $("tr:eq(" + index + ")");
    $("tr:eq(" + row + ")").insertAfter(temp);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCyeQ/), but I'm not sure the function is doing what you want - you need to provide more details in your question if you require further help.

**Update**

Regarding edit in the question: this should be simple, just use

```
function switchDown() {
    $("tr:last").insertBefore("tr:first");
}
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCyeQ/1/))